i have created my npm package and it composed but my npx command not working said The system cannot find the path specified
enter image description here
i was expecting that my npm package will run smoothly but it shows the system cannot find the path specified.i changed my my npm package name and version too but it is still not working.xvxcvxcvxxvxvxvxvxvxvxv

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
